# How to fetch text of the value from data-source in type:'select' ? (x-editable) (laravel 5.2)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, x-editable

I m using [x-editable](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiznp3f097PAhVKuI8KHXawCOsQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvitalets.github.io%2Fx-editable%2Fdocs.html&usg=AFQjCNEC-qfA2aAhGJoM4ZzmTxvjGGQUjA&sig2=OtS6uam8DuuuprIFM-xmiA) in laravel 5.2. I want to store the text of the corresponding value from data-source. I m only  able to store the value in database.

my view:

```
<label>Course:</label><a  href="#" id="course" data-name="course" data-type="select" data-value="" data-pk="{{Auth::user()->id}}" data-source="{1: 'B.tech', 2: 'M.tech'}" data-title="course" data-url="{{route('course')}}"></a>
```

controller:

```
    public function course(Request $request)
{

    $account = new Account();
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $value = $request->get('value');

   $request->user()->accounts()->update([$name => $value]);




    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: I think `twitter-bootstrap` tag is off. Also to make things clear: you'd like to display a value from the database in html? What can you currently see there?

Comment: @Ivan i'm getting '1' and '2' in DB but i want that 'B.tech' and 'M.tech' should be stored in DB.

Comment: You can use Ajax call for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Editable by default creates the `select` with the source object keys as option values and the source values as the options display text. Naturally, when the request is sent, the values (1 or 2 in your case) are sent instead of the texts.

But if the source is an array, the value will be the same as the text. So, you can just do

```
<a ... data-type="select" data-source="['B.tech', 'M.tech']"></a>
```

If you can't or don't want to change that original source of data, instead of setting the source as attribute you can do it when you initialize the component:

```
$('#YOUR_ELEMENT').editable({
    // ...
    source: function () {
        var items = {1: 'B.tech', 2: 'M.tech'};
        return Object.keys(items).map(function(x) {return items[x];});
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question. The point is that I want to separate the value and the text shown, but I still need to get this 'shown text' for some display needs after the select has been selected. (Let's say I want to create a modal window confirming the choosen text, not the value). How can we get this text back ?
The answer before is telling us : don't separate text and value.
Well, I do need to separate them.

Here is the solution I could manage to build thanks to a answer from K Scandrett elsewhere.
I'm looking for the value on the "onSave" event for optimisation.

```
$('.MyTable').on('save', function(e, params) {
    source = $(this).data('editable').input.sourceData
    var selected = $.fn.editableutils.itemsByValue(params.newValue, source); 
    if (selected.length) {
           console.log(selected[0].value);
           console.log(selected[0].text);
    }
});
```

It can even be set directly on the "success" option:

```
$('.MyTable').editable({
   ...
   success: function(responsetxt, newValue) {           
    source = $(this).data('editable').input.sourceData;
    var selected = $.fn.editableutils.itemsByValue(newValue, source); 
    if (selected.length) {
       console.log(selected[0].value);
       console.log(selected[0].text);
    }           
   },
   …
});
```